# How to split a csv file into multiple Lists

Tags: c#, list, csv

I have this code:

```
//new List
List<string> lines = new List<string>();
List<string> lines2 = new List<string>();

// read and write data to list 
for (int i = 0; i < fileName.Length; i++)
{
    string file = @"read\" + Path.GetFileName(fileName[i]);
    // load rows to list.
    lines = File.ReadLines(file).ToList();
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        // Variablen für lines
        string[] entries = line.Split(';');
        int length = entries.Length;
    }
}
```

I am able to read all lines from my csv file into one list but I would like to split the csv file after the 6th column into a second list. How do I do that?

I tired already linq with `lines.Take(6).ToList();` but this just reads the first 6 lines if I'm not mistaken. Same for `Skip()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track, to use `Take` and `Skip`, and then to add the items to their respective lists, you can call the `AddRange` method to add a group of items at once:

```
var filePath = @"c:\public\temp\temp.txt";

var firstSixColumns = new List<string>();
var restOfColumns = new List<string>();

foreach(var fileLine in File.ReadLines(filePath))
{
    var fileLineParts = fileLine.Split(';');
    firstSixColumns.AddRange(fileLineParts.Take(6));  // Add the first 6 entries
    restOfColumns.AddRange(fileLineParts.Skip(6));    // Add the rest of the entries
}
```

If, on the other hand, you are trying to just split the csv lines into two groups of columns, without splitting them further (so each line in `firstSixLines` would represent a row of six columns), then you can use `string.Join` to stitch the columns back again before adding them:

```
foreach(var fileLine in File.ReadLines(filePath))
{
    var fileLineParts = fileLine.Split(';');

    // Join the items before adding them to their respective lists
    firstSixColumns.Add(string.Join(";", fileLineParts.Take(6)));
    restOfColumns.Add(string.Join(";", fileLineParts.Skip(6)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply skip at the point you are reading the column values

```
List<string> entries = line.Split(';').Skip(6).ToList();
```

That said there are plenty of libraries that you can use that are built around reading CSV files. I would recommend searching NuGet for one before you reinvent the wheel.

If you want 2 lists

```
string[] entries = line.Split(';');
List<string> entriesFirst = entries.Take(6).ToList();
List<string> entriesSecond = entries.Skip(6).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, this also helped me a lot sadly i can only mark one answer as correct answer